# Wix post-install and pre-uninstall executables

Tags: wix

I'm using wix to create an installer for my application in Visual Studio. 
I need a post-install executable run after install (which I've got working) and a pre-uninstall executable run before uninstallation.
All of these executables require elevated rights to run (my application, the post-install, and pre-uninstall).

I've scoured the web and stack overflow and found many posts related to this, but none of the solutions seem to work.  Either the executables simply don't run, or, on uninstall I get error

```
There is a problem with this Windows Installer package. A program required for this install to complete could not be run. Contact your support personnel or package vendor.
```

Here is my Directory layout

```
<Fragment>
    <Directory Id="TARGETDIR" Name="SourceDir">
        <Directory Id="ProgramFilesFolder">
            <Directory Id="ROOTDIRECTORY" Name="MyCompany" >
                <Directory Id="FOLDERONE" Name="FolderOne" />
                <Directory Id="UTILITYFOLDER" Name="Utility" />
            </Directory>
        </Directory>
    </Directory>
</Fragment>
```

And a snippet of my File layout

```
<Fragment>
    <DirectoryRef Id="UTILITYINSTALLFOLDER">
        <Component Id="cmpPreInstallId" Guid="{56DC3D0A-E887-4A94-95B3-72825310DC5D}">
            <File Id="filPreInstallId" KeyPath="yes" Source="path_to\PreUninstall.exe" />
        </Component>
        <Component Id="cmpPosUninstallId" Guid="{DE1DE45E-4D7C-4884-BA3E-EC078E265B7C}">
            <File Id="filPostUninstallId" KeyPath="yes" Source="path_to\PostInstall.exe" />
        </Component>
        <!-- obviously there are other files/components -->
    </DirectoryRef>
</Fragment>
<Fragment>
    <ComponentGroup Id="UtilityPublishedComponents">
        <ComponentRef Id="cmpPreInstallId" />
        <ComponentRef Id="cmpPosUninstallId" />
    </ComponentGroup>
</Fragment>
```

And in my Product.wxs

```
<Product ...>

    <!-- The only way I found that actually worked to run the post install was -->
    <UI>
        <UIRef Id="WixUI_Minimal" />
        <Publish Dialog="ExitDialog"
               Control="Finish"
               Event="DoAction"
               Value="PostInstallExe">WIXUI_EXITDIALOGOPTIONALCHECKBOX = 1 and NOT Installed</Publish>
    </UI>
    <Property Id="WIXUI_EXITDIALOGOPTIONALCHECKBOXTEXT" Value="Perform post-install operations." />
    <Property Id="WIXUI_EXITDIALOGOPTIONALCHECKBOX" Value="1"/>
    <Property Id="WixShellExecTarget" Value="[#filPostUninstallId]" />
    <CustomAction Id="PostInstallExe"
                  BinaryKey="WixCA"
                  DllEntry="WixShellExec"
                  Impersonate="yes" />

    <!-- this does not work to run the pre-uninstall -->
    <CustomAction Id="EXECUTE_BEFORE_UNINSTALL"
                  Return="check"
                  Impersonate="yes"
                  Execute="immediate"
                  Directory="UTILITYINSTALLFOLDER"
                  ExeCommand="PreUninstall.exe" />
    <InstallExecuteSequence>
        <Custom Action="EXECUTE_BEFORE_UNINSTALL" Before="RemoveFiles">Installed AND NOT REINSTALL</Custom>
    </InstallExecuteSequence>

    <!-- other stuff plus the feature -->

</Product>
```

Anyone with experience see where this might be going wrong?

I've tried many variations of the CustomAction return, impersonate, execute, etc

Answer (score 0):

Finally got it to work, so hopefully this helps someone.
Not sure what the issue was ... but here!

```
<!-- Setup post install operations -->
<CustomAction Id="PostInstall"
              FileKey="key_to_post_install_exe"
              ExeCommand=""
              Execute="deferred"
              Return="check"
              Impersonate="no" />

<!-- Setup pre uninstall operations -->
<CustomAction Id="PreUninstall"
              FileKey="key_to_pre_uninstall_exe"
              ExeCommand=""
              Execute="deferred"
              Return="ignore"
              Impersonate="no" />

<!-- Add pre and post install operations to the installer -->
<InstallExecuteSequence>
  <Custom Action="PostInstall" Before="InstallFinalize">NOT Installed</Custom>
  <Custom Action="PreUninstall" After="InstallInitialize">Installed</Custom>
</InstallExecuteSequence>
```

Comment: There's a flaw in this answer. Install the product, run a REPAIR from Programs and Features and tell me if your application is in the state you expect it to be.

Comment: After you fix that bug here's another one.  Delete  the uninstall EXE and perform an uninstall.  Your uninstall will appear to succeed  but will your machine will not be as clean as you expect.